# Django file not showing input data in actual website

Tags: python, django

I'm currently attempting to learn how to use django to build a website but my input data in the models is not showing up properly

'''

```
from django.db import models

class products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class typeWork(models.Model):
    work = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    hoursWorked = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

'''

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8sRL.png)

'''

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello')
]
```

'''
[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyvKY.png)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import typeWork


def hello(request):
    products2 = {typeWork.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', {products2})
```

views.py is slightly altered as i was messing with it in order to try and fix it the image shows the code with no alterations and my original issue arising from that code

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmltx.png)

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Work</th>
        <th>Type of Work</th>
        <th>Hours needed</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for products2 in products%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{products2.work}}</td>
            <td>{{products2.genre}}</td>
            <td>{{products2.hoursWorked}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    
</tbody>
```

indes.html is also slightly altered the image will show the original code before i tried fixing it again
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewYwN.png)

[Actual error and what it does show currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxnj2.png)

Comment: Do you have any records to show in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing your `products2` variable through a so-called "context dictionary".

Updated version of `views.py`:
I'm currently attempting to learn how to use django to build a website but my input data in the models is not showing up properly

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import typeWork


def hello(request):
    products2 = typeWork.objects.all()
    context = {"products2": products2}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You had some idea on how to pass these variables when you put the `{}` symbols, but only adding names between these symbols will pass a set. A dictionary would mean the curly braces + a set of key-value pairs.

The main idea is, everytime you're trying to pass data to a view, you'll need to do it via a dictionary. The key you're using will also be used in the template. By replacing your code with the one I wrote, you're going to be okay because your template is iterating through something called `products2`.

Comment: So i tried doing that but my original code essentially did the same thing but without putting the dictionary into an extra variable such as 'context' and it seems to either not be iterating through it properly or something but it still does not provide any input data just the basic headings

Comment: Ok so i think i figured out part of the issue it seems that context in the html file doesn't seem to be taking in any stored data which im confused to as why its not storing any of the data i added in the admin panel